# Can a credit card machine refund to a different card than the one inserted?

Tags: credit-card

I purchased a $279.99 holiday feast from Whole Foods online. When I inquired as to what time I was to collect the meal, they said I didn't have an order. One week later, my card was charged. I physically went to the store, they found the order online, agreed to credit my card, and had me put my card into the machine. When I looked at the receipt, a completely different card had been credited. (I knew this as the last 4 digits belong to a card I do not own.) Whole Foods insists they did nothing wrong. My credit card company is investigating. This has never happened to me before - can a credit card machine credit a card other than the one inserted? They just keep insisting that they credited the card put into the machine. They are wrong: yes, I put a card into the machine, and yes they applied a credit, it's just that those two transactions did not connect. Is  it possible for this to happen? How? And is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: You could wait until you credit company has finished investigating. They are normally pretty good about this, and it makes little sense to do anything until they have concluded their investigations.

Comment: *Is it possible for this to happen?  How?* Without having witnessed what the Whole Foods employee did, that's a hard question to answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was really just hoping that someone might have some insight into how this happens, of if it's happened to anyone else. I've never experienced my refund being applied to a mysterious credit card.

Comment: Could there be some kind of "virtual credit card" effect happening? E.g. when you paid for the order, could it have been charged to a "virtual" card number (that would link back to your "real" card number). When you got the refund, the real card proved it was "you", but the receipt quoted the original (virtual) number that had been charged? Do you have an acknowledgement of the original order quoting a partial card number, and does _that_ match what's on the receipt? (I've no idea if this is how virtual credit cards work... just thinking aloud).

Comment: @TripeHound there are a handful of things that could qualify as "virtual" credit cards (for instance, most phone-based payment apps use single-use numbers they generate for each transaction. And some banks will let you digitally generate a temporary number for use online, etc.) but since the OP specifically mentions inserting a physical card, the machine only could have read the actual card number. Of course, we don't know what the employee did at the POS machine once the card had been read.

Comment: @dwizum I'm only throwing it out as a (distant?) possibility, just in case it triggers a "eureka" moment... I've no idea if it _is_ possible, but... if the OP _did_ use a virtual card number to buy online, while there should be no way for the shop to link from that to the real card number, it is just about conceivable (to me, but I'm strange :-) ) that in using the real card to trigger the refund, the card-processor caused the receipt/acknowledgement to show the virtual card's last four digits, since that was the one that was originally charged.

Comment: The chip in your card might be "broken", saying that it's card number is different from what's on the card.  It **should**, though, **not** happen.

Comment: You can't really break a chip in a way that would cause it to still work and submit a different card number. And at any rate, if the card *was* somehow submitting totally random numbers, the chances of it submitting one that is a legitimate card number are extremely low. If the card was submitting numbers that were basic modifications to the real number (i.e. single digit errors, transposition of sequential digits) it would almost certainly fail the Luhn test and get rejected.

Comment: @dwizum: Regarding "break a chip in a way that would cause it to still work and submit a different card number" -- https://www.experian.com/blogs/ask-experian/this-new-chip-theft-scam-will-blow-your-mind/

Comment: Usually refunds are made to the same credit card that was used for the purchase (because it doesn't cost the merchant anything). By definition you can't "refund" a card that wasn't used for the purchase.